# How do I obtain / compute values like FLT_MAX and FLT_EPSILON with LLVM?

Tags: floating-point, llvm, llvmlite

If my code is generating LLVM SSA for a platform that is possibly different than the one on which it is currently running, how do I obtain values like `FLT_MAX` or `FLT_EPSILON` (or the same for doubles, or any other floating point width)?

I'm guessing it's not correct, in general, to obtain those values for my own system and use them. It's also not an acceptable solution to delegate the question to `clang` or `gcc`.

When generating LLVM code, how do I know what value to emit for `FLT_MAX`?

Comment: I haven't needed those, but I have generated other constants using [ConstantExpr](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html) and the constant's definition. LLVM then folded my constant expression to a simple constant.

Comment: It's very likely that your  target (as well as your development machine for that matter) uses IEEE-754 floating point types.  Does LLVM even support anything else?  So you can just look up the value, and maybe write it as a hex float.

Comment: @NateEldredge If LLVM's FloatType and DoubleType are guaranteed to be IEEE754 32 and 64 bit on all platforms, that might do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

`FLT_MAX` / `FLT_EPSILON` are entities specific to C/C++ and are not connected with LLVM. So, you'd need to resort to a C/C++ compiler in order to derive this. Alternatively, you'd need to keep the list of supported platforms and hard-code these values there for each supported platforms.

Comment: I believe OP is using `FLT_MAX` and `FLT_EPSILON` as placeholders for the concepts they provide values for, not the language-specific definitions of them. In other words, OP wants to know how to reference the maximum floating-point value and the so-called “epsilon” measure of precision of the floating-point format in LLVM IR.